# $\sup A =-\inf(-A)$ Proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $A\neq\emptyset$ and bounded above. Let $-A=\{-x\ | \ x\in A\}.$ Prove that $\sup A=-\inf -A.$

We need to show that $-\inf -A$ is the least upper bound of $A.$ Suppose $x \in A.$ Then $-x \in -A,$ and, hence $-x\ge \inf -A. $  This implies that $x \le -\inf -A.$  Thus $-\inf -A$ is an upper bound of $A.$  Let $\beta$ be any upper bound of $A.$  Thus $\beta \ge x$ for every $ x \in A.$  This implies that $-\beta \le -x$ for every $x \in A$ which tells us that $y \ge -\beta$ for all $y \in -A.$  Hence $-\beta$ is a lower bound of $-A.$  Hence $-\beta \le \inf -A,$ $\beta \ge -\inf -A,$ and so $-\inf -A$ is the least upper bound of $A.$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Nice. Thank you @copper.hat

Comment: Wow, that 'dup' thing has never happened so fast before!